# Enum case 'failed' not found in type 'SKError.Code'

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

So I am implementing in-app purchase in to my app and I am watching Jared Davidson's tutorial on how to do this (great tutorial) However there is one problem, it is 6 months old. I have not finished it yet but I just ran into a couple errors when setting up the alerts.

```
extension ViewController {

        func alertWithTitle(title: String, message : String) -> UIAlertController {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            return alert


    }

        func showAlert(alert : UIAlertController) {
            guard let _ = self.presentedViewController else {
                self.present(alert, animated:  true, completion: nil)
                return
            }


        }
        func alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result : RetrieveResults) -> UIAlertController {
            if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
                let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
                return alertWithTitle(title: product.localizedTitle, message: "\(product.localizedDescription) - \(priceString)")
            }
            else if let ivalidProductID = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
                return alertWithTitle(title: "Could not retrieve product info", message: "Invalid product identifier: \(ivalidProductID)")
            }
            else {
                let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error. Please Contact Support"
                return alertWithTitle(title: "Could not retreive product info", message: errorString)
            }
        }
        func alertForPurchaseResult(result : PurchaseResult) -> UIAlertController {
            switch result {
            case .success(let product):
                print("Purchase Succesful: \(product.productId)")

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                return alertWithTitle(title: "Thank you for your kind donation!", message: "Purchase completed")
            case .error(let error):
                print("Purchase Failed: \(error)")
                switch error.code {
                case .failed(let error):
                    if (error as NSError).domain == SKErrorDomain {
                        return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Check your internet connection or try again later.")
                    }
                    else {
                        return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Unkown Error. Please Contact Support")
                    }
                case .invalidProductID(let productID):
                    return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "\(productID) is not a valid product identifier")
                case .noProductIdentifier:
                    return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "Product not found")
                case .paymentNotAllowed:
                    return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Failed", message: "You are not allowed to make payments")

                }

        }

    }
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

> "Enum case 'failed' not found in type "SKError.Code"

> "Enum case 'invalidProductID' not found in type "SKError.Code

> "Enum case 'noProductIdentifier' not found in type "SKError.Code"

I know I get these errors because they updated it or something and there are new cases but I am not sure how to convert them over like which one goes with which?

I apologize, I am just really confused right now! All help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The framework that the tutorial uses (SwiftyStoreKit) recently [changed](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/releases/tag/0.8.0) how error checking API works. The updated should be:

```
    func alertForPurchaseResult(result : PurchaseResult) -> UIAlertController {
        switch result {
        case .success(let product):
            return alertWithTitle(title: "Thank You", message: "Purchase completed")
        case .error(let error):
            switch error.code {
            case .unknown: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "Unknown error. Please contact support")
            case .clientInvalid: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "Not allowed to make the payment")
            case .paymentCancelled: return alertWithTitle(title: "Payment Cancelled", message: "Payment Cancelled")
            case .paymentInvalid: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "The purchase identifier was invalid")
            case .paymentNotAllowed: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "The device is not allowed to make the payment")
            case .storeProductNotAvailable: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "The product is not available in the current storefront")
            case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
            case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "Could not connect to the network")
            default: return alertWithTitle(title: "Purchase Error", message: "Unknown error")
            }
        }  
    }
```